# What am I getting wrong in my pandas lambda map?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, lambda

I'm trying to find the percentile of a dataframe which observations in a second dataframe would belong to, and I thought a lambda function would do the trick here like so:

```
df1.var1.map(lambda x: np.percentile(df2.var1, x))
```

which I read as for each `x` in the series `df1.var1`, apply the function `np.percentile(df2.var1, x)`, which finds the percentile of `x` in the series `df2.var1`. For some reason, I'm getting the error

```
kth(=-9223372036854775599) out of bounds (209)
```

where 209 is the length of `df2`, but I have no idea what the `kth` part refers to. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

FULL ERROR:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-02d5cacfecd4> in <module>()
----> 1 df1.var1.map(lambda x: np.percentile(df2.var1, x))
   C:\Users\ngudat\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in map(self, arg, na_action)
   2043                                      index=self.index).__finalize__ (self)
   2044         else:
-> 2045             mapped = map_f(values, arg)
   2046             return self._constructor(mapped,
   2047                                      index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:62187)()

<ipython-input-82-02d5cacfecd4> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df.qof.map(lambda x: np.percentile(prac_prof.qof, x))

C:\Users\ngudat\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc in percentile(a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
   3266     r, k = _ureduce(a, func=_percentile, q=q, axis=axis, out=out,
   3267                     overwrite_input=overwrite_input,
-> 3268                     interpolation=interpolation)
   3269     if keepdims:
   3270         if q.ndim == 0:

C:\Users\ngudat\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc in _ureduce(a, func, **kwargs)
   2995         keepdim = [1] * a.ndim
   2996 
-> 2997     r = func(a, **kwargs)
   2998     return r, keepdim
   2999 

C:\Users\ngudat\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc in _percentile(a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
   3370         weights_above.shape = weights_shape
   3371 
-> 3372         ap.partition(concatenate((indices_below, indices_above)),axis=axis)
   3373 
   3374         # ensure axis with qth is first

ValueError: kth(=-9223372036854775599) out of bounds (209)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: Added the full error above.

Comment: Looks like your error happens when calling `np.percentile()`. Make sure the arguments you're passing are correct: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Answer (score 2):

Percentile will not give you what you need here, it takes a percentile and gives you the value. You need the opposite. You should rank the entries in the column and calculate the percentiles from that:

```
import pandas as pd
aa = [1,3,2,4,11,8,9]
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=aa,columns=['xx'])
dd['rank']=dd['xx'].rank()
dd['percentile'] = dd['rank']/len(dd)
```

This gives you the percentile corresponding to each entry:

```
   xx  rank  percentile
0   1     1    0.142857
1   3     3    0.428571
2   2     2    0.285714
3   4     4    0.571429
4  11     7    1.000000
5   8     5    0.714286
6   9     6    0.857143
```